# Oracle zombie connections with Tomcat 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, ojdbc, tomcat9

I have created a very simple web service on Tomcat 9.0.12 that's each time it's called i create a connection to the Database ( Oracle 12 ) using a DataSource ( defined in the conf/context.xml file ) then before returning the response to the client, it closes the connection to the Database.

But if i check the active session on my Database it shows that the connection is still alive, so i have a lot of "zombie" connection to my Database.

I have used more or less the same code to a client side program, and in this case the program close the connection. Maybe can be a Tomcat bad configuration?

How can i fix this?

Thank you!

*conf/context.xml*

```
<Resource maxWaitMillis="5000" 
          maxIdle="100" 
          maxActive="200" 
          password="PASSWORD" 
          username="USER" 
          url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@/192.168.1.248:1521/PRD" 
          driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
          type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
          auth="Container" 
          name="jdbc_Connection"/>
```

*Java*

```
public String method() {

    try {
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("START");
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------");


        DataSource ds = (DataSource) InitialContext.doLookup("java:comp/env/jdbc_Connection");

        Connection DB = ds.getConnection();


        String sql ="SELECT VAR FROM TABLE_NAME";
        PreparedStatement stmt = null;
        try {
            stmt = DB.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs    = stmt.executeQuery();

            while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("rs->"+rs.getString(1));
            }

            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
        }finally{
            if(stmt != null){
                try {
                    stmt.close();
                } catch (SQLException ex) {

                }
            }
        }


        System.out.println("CLOSE");
        DB.close();

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } 

    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("END");
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------");


    return "HELLO";
}
```

Comment: Using `Resource` creates a connection pool. Also, using 100 idle and 200 max might be a bit overkill if this is an application that doesn't get hundreds of requests per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're not zombies. They're waiting in a connection pool for reuse. Creating connections is expensive, so you don't want to (really) close them for nothing. As Andreas pointed out, connection pools return a wrapped connection, where calling `close()` doesn't really close it. It's just returned to the pool.

Your configuration says that there can be up to 100 idle connections in the pool, and 200 total connections. As Mark said, this is probably [way too much](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/wiki/About-Pool-Sizing).

Comment: *"you don't want to close them for nothing"* To clarify, the application code should always close them, but the close done by the code is intercepted by the connection pool logic added by Tomcat, and the connection is instead returned to the pool for reuse. When the application code then later tries to create a new connection, it will instead get an existing connection from the pool *(much faster!)*. Pools can be tuned for better performance, see [BasicDataSource Configuration Parameters](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/configuration.html).